# Can I apply for a new Canadian visit visa before the old one expires?

Tags: visas, canada, visa-expiration, visa-renewals

I have 1 year Canadian visitor visa with multiple entry, this visa is only for one year as my passport will expire within one year.

Now I have new passport, my visa will expire on 20th April 2019 and I am planning to travel Canada in May 2019.

Can I apply for fresh visa before it expires or do I have to wait untill it expires before doing so?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for it to expire:

> Wait for it to expire.
>
> You can't have two TRVs valid at the same time. Some offices may cancel the one you have and issue you another one if you are in that small gap that makes it reasonable to do so, but most of the times your request will be denied (not refused) as you already have a valid document.

([Source](https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/re-apply-visitor-visa-before-expiry-of.275999/))